# Check if a letter exists before a certain phrase in a word

Tags: regex

My guess is this needs lookaheads/behinds and i am not to familiar with them.

The problem is simple lets say i have the word

```
submarine
```

And i want my regex to match IF there is the letter **r** in BUT the letter **s** cant occur before the letter **r**. So **submarine** would be failed match, since s does occur before r. The word **word** would be a match since there is no **s** in it at all the string **wersr** would also be a match because i only need to check for the first **r** and before the first r there is only **wer** which doesnt contain **s**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go for lookarounds . Simply the below regex would do the job.

```
^[^s]*r.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uN0eP5/5)

Comment: yep thats it will mark it as correct answear when i can

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=[^s]*r).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/16

Comment: it won't match `rssss`

Comment: Lookahead is an overkill here .

Comment: check with the debugging steps in the demo link.

Comment: Whatif the user has the language which won't support lookahead?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `My guess is this needs lookaheads/behinds and i am not to familiar with them.`

Answer (score 0):

To match words with an "r" that is not preceded by an "s" anywhere in the word:

```
\b[^s\W]*r\w*\b
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/vKogmKgJwG) matching "rat", "arsenic" and "more", but not "misread" or "submarine"